# Setting tabIndex nicely in VueJS when iterating over multiple objects

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I have a couple of nested objects I need to iterate over to create inputs. I've dumbed it down to an example below. I would like to set tabIndexes in these inputs.

```
<div v-for="(iv, ik, ii) in {a: 'x', b: 'x'}" :key="ii">
  <div v-for="(jv, jk, ji) in {a: 'y', b: 'y'}" :key="ji">
    <div v-for="(kv, kk, ki) in {a: 'z', b: 'z', c: 'z'}" :key="ki">
      <input type="text" :tabindex="(ii * 100) + (ji * 10) + ki" />
      <label>{{(ii * 100) + (ji * 10) + ki}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to be able to set my tabindex to 0, 1, 2, 3, etc? I found that setting a third arg on the v-for provides a numeric index, but what I've got seems a little convoluted. Is there a better way I can go about this?

The above results in output like the following:

```
[___________] 0
[___________] 1
[___________] 2
[___________] 10
[___________] 11
[___________] 12
[___________] 100
[___________] 101
[___________] 102
[___________] 110
[___________] 111
[___________] 112
```

Which works, but seems less than ideal. I know the tab key will work as intended if they're sequential and that gaps seem fine. But is there a cleaner way I could get 1 through 12 instead of the staggered numbers I've got? Basically like a running index (x++, etc) for each time I hit the ?

I tried setting an int in the 'data' and then a method to increment that, but quickly threw myself into an infinite re-rendering loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, just setting `tabindex="0"` on all of your `<input>` elements will have exactly the effect that you want. From an accessibility standpoint, setting tab indices other than 0 or -1 is generally a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the flexbox "order" attribute to reposition a few of these items, so having them all at 0 will result in some "random" tab functionality from the perspective of the end user. I didn't want to overflow this question with requirements, as I'll be able to (inc|dec)rement the numbers as needed based on the flexbox ordering. This is for a non-public facing application that has a ton of input fields, so usability & accessibility will have to be figured out for sure. I'll do more research on what you said about setting tab indexes.

Comment: Actually, if you're using flexbox order, then that's one of the reasonable use cases for non-zero tabindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a trick to doing this, but it's a hack, and not exactly a best practice

Template:

```
{{numitems = 0 | hide}}
<div v-for="(iv, ik, ii) in {a: 'x', b: 'x'}" :key="ii">
  <div v-for="(jv, jk, ji) in {a: 'y', b: 'y'}" :key="ji">
    <div v-for="(kv, kk, ki) in {a: 'z', b: 'z', c: 'z'}" :key="ki">
      <input type="text" :tabindex="numitems += 1" />
      <label>{{(ii * 100) + (ji * 10) + ki}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

script `hide` Filter definition

```
filters: {
  hide: function(value){
    return ''
  }
}
```

you don't need the hide filter, but it ensures that you don't put anything into the template during definition. You can also define `numitems` in `data`. And use methods to reset and increment.

---

another option is setting up a computed value that uses the number you generate as an index to the incremental values without any gaps.

Whenever your objects' keys change, you can do the calculation, generating the keys either using your method, or using an object.

here's an example that uses `${ik}_${jk}_${kk}` as the key

```
tabIndexVals(): {
  let c = 0;
  let o = {};
  Object.keys(i).forEach(ik => {
    Object.keys(i[ik]).forEach(jk => {
      Object.keys(i[ik][jk]).forEach(kk => {
        let key = `${ik}_${jk}_${kk}`;
        o[key] = c;
        c++;
      })
    })
  })
  return o;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first method you suggested does feel a bit hacky, but worked exactly as I needed it to. As mentioned in a comment above I had to do a little manipulation of numItems based on certain conditions due to using flexbox 'order' to arrange inputs and I was able to do that with your solution.